# Parcel not finding .env variables

Tags: parceljs

I have a simple setup, .env file at the same level as my `package.json` with:

```
API_URL=http://localhost:8080
```

Then, in my js I've written something like:

```
console.log(process.env);
// {}
```

I've tried deleting my `.cache` but no dice. I'm looking at their [docs about env variables](https://parceljs.org/env.html), and saw something about `parcel-builder` should be in the `package.json` so I added that as a long shot, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you [figured it out](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/2984). For other people with the same question:

The full `process.env` object is not accessible for security reasons, but individual properties like `process.env.API_URL` should work.